# how to modify the auto generated source code in JDeveloper 12c

Tags: java, jdeveloper

when using JDev 12c Design time, the code generated in source time is read only and i need to modify or add something with code, and unfortunately the main method generated is read only

Comment: No you don't. There are ways to customize it, surely. Never modify generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a Swing application - This is probably because you are using Matisse, and then the code is locked.